# compare and Select three top results

Tags: mysql, database

I have four tables
Table Names below:

1. Name_tbl
2. Sports_tbl
3. Arts_tbl
4. Science_tbl

All the tables are connected by a unique id say 'name_id' that is the primary key of the table 'Name_tbl'. Now I will query for a name( in the Name_tbl) and lets say it returns me 10 results. I have to show 3 three results who are best depending on the average of the marks scored that are stored in the 'Sports_tbl, Arts_tbl, Science_tbl'. 
So what is the optimal solution for this using Mysql. As the results returned on the first instance can get upto 100 or more.

Thanks, any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: I will accept the correct result, but the query is returning this error:
#2006- MySQL server has gone away 
Don't know the reason. So was trying to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming numbers are stored in score column of each table):

```
SELECT name_tbl.*, ( (arts_tbl.score+science_tbl.score+sports_tbl.score)/3 ) as avg_score
FROM name_tbl 
LEFT JOIN arts_tbl ON name_tbl.name_id = arts_tbl.name_id 
LEFT JOIN sports_tbl ON name_tbl.name_id = sports_tbl.name_id 
LEFT JOIN science_tbl ON name_tbl.name_id = science_tbl.name_id 
ORDER BY avg_score DESC
LIMIT 3
```